# Transfer function for amplitude modulation

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

What is the transfer function of the amplitude modulation element where the output is simply the input multiplied by a sinusoidal wave with a constant amplitude?

[image]

Comment: You should  post this question on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @JeanMarie  It is a mathematically well-defined question that can be posed regardless of the application I have in mind, which is actually not signal processing at all. I mentioned amplitude modulation because that is the common name for this element.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

$$
G(s) = \frac{\omega s}{s^2 + \omega^2}
$$

If you input a step to this transfer function the output will be a sinusoidal wave  with frequency $\omega = 2 \pi f$ and the amplitude equal to the height of the step.

Here a plot with 2 Hz:

[image]

Comment: What is described in the question is nonlinear so can't be described by a transfer function in general.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Is there any linear approximation of this process?

Comment: @Tarek Ok I missunderstood the question then, I thought you meant the transfer function of the sine generator. If you multiply the signal, you get a nonlinear system.

Comment: @Tarek It is possible to dynamically approximate the multiplication of the sinusoid with the other signal using a Volterra Series expansion and the generalized FRF. But don't expect nice straight forward computations, this usually involves multidimensional convolution, and you need to know your exact input signal spectrum. And this all is just valid for just a limited domain... Maybe better to do it databased

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Amplitude modulation follows the superposition principle, so how is it nonlinear?

Comment: @Tarek amplitude modulation is linear, so my statement that it is nonlinear is indeed incorrect. However, amplitude modulation is not time invariant and both are needed in order for it to be able to be described by a transfer function. You can sort of circumvent the time invariance by only allowing the input to change every period of the sinusoidal wave, as also shown in this answer from SampleTime.